# How to web scrape the starting lineup for the NBA?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am new to web scraping and could use some help. I would like to scrape the NBA's starting lineup, the teams and the player's positions using Xpath. I only starting on the names because I was running into an issue.

Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring 


url = "https://www.lineups.com/nba/lineups"

content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)


for nba, bball_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//tr[contains(@class,"t-content")]')):
    names = bball_row.xpath('.//span[@_ngcontent-c5="long-player-name"]/text()')[0]
    print(names)
```

It looks like the program runs without error but the names do not print. Any tips on how to parse using Xpath more efficiently would be greatly appreciated. I tried messing with Xpath helper and Xpath Finder. Maybe there are some tricks on there in order to make the process easier. Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: The data you're looking to scrape is being injected via Javascript. You cannot scrape it the way that you're doing it. Try looking at Selenium.

Comment: Thanks @aris! I will look into Selenium and will update my code if I figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Required content located inside `script` node that looks like

```
<script nonce="STATE_TRANSFER_TOKEN">window['TRANSFER_STATE'] = {...}</script>
```

You can try to do following to extract data as simple Python dictionary:

```
import re
import json
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.lineups.com/nba/lineups").text
dictionary = json.loads(re.search(r"window\['TRANSFER_STATE'\]\s=\s(\{.*\})<\/script>", source).group(1))
```

*Optionally: Paste the output of `dictionary` [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) and click "Beautify" to see data as readable JSON*

Then you can access required value by key, e.g.

```
for player in dictionary['https://api.lineups.com/nba/fetch/lineups/gateway']['data'][0]['home_players']:
    print(player['name'])

Kyrie Irving
Jaylen Brown
Jayson Tatum
Gordon Hayward
Al Horford

for player in dictionary['https://api.lineups.com/nba/fetch/lineups/gateway']['data'][0]['away_players']:
    print(player['name'])

D.J. Augustin
Evan Fournier
Jonathan Isaac
Aaron Gordon
Nikola Vucevic
```

**Update**

I guess I just made it overcomplicated :)

It should be as simple as below:

```
import requests

source = requests.get("https://api.lineups.com/nba/fetch/lineups/gateway").json()
for player in source['data'][0]['away_players']:
        print(player['name'])
```

**Update 2**

To get all teams lineups use below:

```
import requests

source = requests.get("https://api.lineups.com/nba/fetch/lineups/gateway").json()

for team in source['data']:
    print("\n%s players\n" % team['home_route'].capitalize())
    for player in team['home_players']:
        print(player['name'])
    print("\n%s players\n" % team['away_route'].capitalize())
    for player in team['away_players']:
        print(player['name'])
```

Comment: Nicely done. How did you figure out that the link to the desired result might be within any script @sir Andersson? Is there any trick to know using dev tools?

Comment: @SIM , the first thing to try is simply to copy part of required data -> open page source (right click on page-> View page source) -> Ctrl + F -> Ctrl + V. If data is not there, then it most likely comes from XHR. But in this case data was in `script` node in a JSON format and the first key of JSON is the link to API. No magic :)

Comment: This worked perfectly as advertised... Thank you so much @Andersson for your help. Amazing work! =)

Comment: I just noticed that all of the teams and players are not being printed. I initially thought it was because all of the starters weren't in yet but the starters are updated now. I see 7 teams printed from the code above and the top team does not have a title. Any advice @Andersson? I am very grateful for your help sir.

Comment: @AbleArcher , hmm... I got 6 teams starters for 3 current games... Can you clarify what exactly is wrong with the output as I'm not sure what output you want to get? Make sure that you're using code from 2nd Update block

Comment: Actually there are only 3 games today... My apologies. The output is correct like you stated. All of the starting players and teams are printed. It looks like the 76er's players are printed twice, though. I see Markelle Fultz printed once at the top and once under the 76ers. Other than that it's flawless. I am very appreciative of your help @Andersson! Thank you so much for the learning experience. =)

Comment: Actually this code works perfectly all around thanks to @Andersson. I believe I was adding an extra line of code. Thanks again to everyone that helped!

Comment: Update 2 works like a charm. The issue I had was adding update 1 and update 2 together. This code is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks again @Andersson! Is there anyway you can help me turn this code into a pandas dataframe? I would love to be able to import this data to excel.

Comment: @AbleArcher Sorry, I don't have much experience with Pandas... You can submit new ticket regarding this issue and add "pandas" tag. I'm sure that Pandas guru will help you :)

Comment: Thank you sir @Andersson for your time. It was very helpful. =)

Comment: Is there anyway I can contact you for future work @Andersson? My contact info is on my profile.

Comment: @AbleArcher , If you have any coding issues you can always post new question here on SO. I'll take a look when I have time. Also there are many other users that can help. Currently I'm working on a Project so I'm not sure I have much time to mentor